# Selecting cells with less than three neighbors

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

With a lengthy code I've created the following grid:

[image]

I would like to select and delete every single row, similar to the one you can see in the bottom left part of the the image. I would like to know if there's a way to make a selection which selects every cell which has less than three neighbors.